# Changing Behavior of List Selection Using Control & Shift Keys with jQuery Optimization - UPDATE 2

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic, selection

I'm working on a page that has a list of people. The user needs to be able to select one or multiple rows. I'd like the page to behave similarly to Windows Explorer, where clicking only selects one person at a time, but the Control and Shift keys allow for multiple selections.

I've written up a sample with jsFiddle, and it's working on Firefox and IE10 as far as I can tell.

```
var first_num;
var second_num;
var low_num;
var high_num;
var i;
var selected;
var multiple_lines_selected = 0;

$('label').click(function(e){
    if (e.shiftKey){
        multiple_lines_selected = 1;
        $('input').prop('checked', false);
        first_num = parseInt(selected.replace(' input','').replace('#n',''));
        second_num = parseInt($(this).attr('ID').replace('n',''));
        low_num = Math.min(first_num,second_num);
        high_num = Math.max(first_num,second_num);
        i = low_num;
        while (i<=high_num) {
            $('#n'+i +' input').prop('checked', true);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else if (e.ctrlKey){
        multiple_lines_selected = 1;
        selected = '#'+$(this).attr('ID') +' input';
        if (!$(selected).is(':checked')) {$(selected).prop('checked', true);}
        else {$(selected).prop('checked', false);}
    }
    else {
        selected = '#'+$(this).attr('ID') +' input';
        $('input').not(selected).prop('checked', false);
        if (multiple_lines_selected) {
            setTimeout(function(event){$(selected).prop('checked', true);});
        }
        multiple_lines_selected = 0;
    }
});
$('label').mousedown(function(e){
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

The HTML is simply a repeating

```
<label id="n1" class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" />Person 1
</label>
```

I appreciate any advice or help!

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mExp4/1/

**EDIT 1**: On Chrome, I've found a weird bug. If I click on the row while holding the control key, everything behaves as expected. If I click on the actual checkbox however, nothing changes. Thoughts?

**EDIT 2**: The "bug" I found in Chrome also exists in Firefox and IE, I just wasn't paying attention. And I'm not sure it's a bug, but I still can't figure out how to get around it. When I click on the label, things work just fine. When I click on the checkbox, while using the control key, things don't work so well.

I think this goes back to the fact that when you hold control or shift, clicking a label won't activate the checkbox inside, when there is no javascript. This thwarted my attempt to use .change instead of .click. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to fix the problem, but it's a hacked out answer, so I'm still open to better options. Basically, I added an invisible div that hovers on top of the checkbox. It is inside the  though, so clicking on it still activates the checkbox. It activates it via the label however, instead of both the label and the checkbox at once.

For the sake of people who don't use javascript, it starts out with `display:none` and is shown by the script. One goal here being to have someone that is graceful when disabled.

```
.checkbox_overlay {
    height:40px;
    width:20px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-10px;
    float:left;
}

<label id="n1" class="row">
    <div class="checkbox_overlay"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" />Person 1
</label>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mExp4/4/